# Trouble decoding email using gmail API

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, base64, gmail-api

I am having a hard time getting python to read my emails.  I am trying to pull information from the body of the email. The problem I am running into is when I run the code on the email directly from the original source, even after running it through the base64 decoder, it still returns the base64 data that is unreadable. BUT if I forward that same email to myself, so the code is then going over the forwarded email, it works perfectly and decodes the entire email appropriately. Here is the function I am using to get the email body. I have noticed that the content_type is "text" when it is directly from the source, but it is reading it as 'multipart' when i forward it to myself. ANY HELP is greatly appreciated. I am at a loss for where to go from here.

Thanks in advance!

```
def get_message(service, user_id, msg_id):
    try:
        # Makes the connection and GETS the emails in RAW format.
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, format='raw').execute()
        # Changes format from RAW to ASCII
        msg_raw = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))
        # Changes format type again
        msg_str = email.message_from_bytes(msg_raw)
        # This line checks what the content is, if multipart (plaintext and html) or single part
        content_types = msg_str.get_content_maintype()
        print(content_types)
        if content_types == 'multipart':
            # Part1 is plaintext and part2 is html text
            part1, part2 = msg_str.get_payload()
            raw_email = part1.get_payload()
            remove_char = ["|", "=20", "=C2=A0"]
            for i in remove_char:
                raw_email = raw_email.replace(i, "")
            raw_email = "".join([s for s in raw_email.strip().splitlines(True) if s.strip()])
            print('Inside correct part')
            print(raw_email)
            return str(raw_email)
        else:
            print('Inside the Else')
            print(msg_str.get_payload())
            return msg_str.get_payload()
    except:
        print('An error has occured during the get_message function.')
```

Edit:  Here is what this function prints out when looking over this from the original source:

```
text
Inside the Else 
PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWwgUFVCTElDICItLy93M2MvL2R0ZCB4aHRtbCAxLjAgdHJhbnNpdGlvbmFs
Ly9lbiIgImh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL3RyL3hodG1sMS9kdGQveGh0bWwxLXRyYW5zaXRpb25h
bC5kdGQiPjxodG1sIHN0eWxlPSJtYXJnaW46IDA7cGFkZGluZzogMDtmb250LWZhbWlseTogJ0hl
bHZldGljYSBOZXVlJywgJ0hlbHZldGljYScsIEhlbHZldGljYSwgQXJpYWwsIHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7
Plus about 100 lines of stuff like this.
```

Here is what it prints out from the same email if I forward it to myself:

```
multipart
Inside correct part
---------- Forwarded message ---------
From: <originalSource@email.com>
Date: Wed, Jun 10, 2020 at 10:34 AM
Subject: You added cash to your Account
To: <xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>


[image: card] Account ending in XXXX
Hi, XXXX XXXX,
Success!

You added cash with
```

Answer (score -1):

The base64 will decode the data as a string, not as bytes. Therefore you should change this

```
msg_str = email.message_from_bytes(msg_raw)
```

for this

```
msg_str = email.message_from_string(msg_raw)
```

Check out [this documentation example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#examples) in Python for more info regarding this.

Comment: When i change that line to email.message_from_string(msg_raw) I get this error. TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Comment: Hi ! Which version of Python are you using? ```message_from_string``` will work well only with Python 2. However, I have tested ```message_from_bytes``` in Python 3 and it worked fine for me retrieving the right information. Does this issue only happen with a specific message or with several? And if so, could you describe briefly what is the type of content of this message (*do not include any sensitive data*) like it has non ascii characters or punctuation marks etc. Thanks :D